# ML.NET - Normalizing date time data

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

so the case is to simply forecast some feature value Y (let it be type float) given  specific time T.

Currently I've got simple 2 column data like 
2019-10-18 10:00  | 1.0
2019-10-18 12:00  | 2.5

and so on.

Simple input data can represent changing values of sinusoid function f(x)=sin(x) in time.

I'm interested in how to convert date time series in ML.NET that later I want to ask engine to predict feature value Y for given date time T (maybe given in form of unix time stamp?)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend converting to Unix timestamps, yes. ML.NET algorithms use floats as features, so timestamps will work fine.